# What does reputation cap exactly mean?

Tags: discussion

A user can earn a maximum of [200](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) reputation, but my daily reputation gain never stops at 200, it always goes higher than 200 (whenever it gets chance ;). So what does repo cap *exactly* mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The score that you get by answer acceptance and bounty is not restricted by the cap.

Comment: Also this is calculated for each stackexchange community.

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32161/309922) on Meta.SE